# speed up reading data in fortran read(1)columnA,columnB,columnC - only want column A & C?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have a series of data:

columnABC,columnDEF,columnG

I only want column ABC and columnG, is there a way to skip columnsDEF?

```
   allocate(ABC(1:3,1:N))
   read(1)ABC
   allocate(DEF(1:3,1:N))
   read(1)DEF
   deallocate(DEF)
   allocate(G(N))
   read(1)G

   use ABC and G for calculations
```

Do I have to allocate and read DEF in order to access G? There has to be a way to skip over these next three without actually populating the allocated array DEF? Or is what I've got pretty standard procedure? Thanks Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for an unformatted sequential acess read, simply doing  `read(1)` will skip the  data record, no need to declare/allocate DEF.

Comment: unformatted sequential access files have header data describing the length of each record.  more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751185/fortran-unformatted-file-format