# Writing large Fortran binary files with access=stream

Tags: fortran, binaryfiles, intel-fortran, fortran2003

I am having some problems understanding the formatting of binary files that I am writing using Fortran. I use the following subroutine to write binary files to disk:

```
SUBROUTINE write_field(d,m,outfile)

    IMPLICIT NONE    
    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: d(m,m,m)
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: m
    CHARACTER(len=256), INTENT(IN) :: outfile

    OPEN(7,file=outfile,form='unformatted',access='stream')
    WRITE(7) d
    CLOSE(7)

END SUBROUTINE write_field
```

My understanding of the `access=stream` option was that this would suppress the standard header and footer that comes with a Fortran binary (see [Fortran unformatted file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751185/fortran-unformatted-file-format)).

If I write a file with `m=512` then my expectation is that the file should be `4 x 512^3 bytes = 536870912 bytes ~ 513 Mb` however they are in fact 8 bytes longer than this, coming in at `536870920 bytes`. My guess is that these extra bytes are the 4 byte header and footers, which I had wanted to suppress by using `access='stream'`.

The situation becomes confusing to me if I write a file with `m=1024` then my expectation is that the file should be `4 x 1024^3 bytes = 4294967296 ~ 4.1 Gb` however they are in fact 24(!) bytes longer than this, coming in at `4294967320 bytes`. I do not understand why there are 24 extra bytes here, which would seem to correspond to 6(!) headers or footers.

My questions are:

(a) Is it possible to get Fortran to write a binary with no headers or footers?

(b) If the answer to (a) is 'no' then can I ensure that the larger binary has the same header and footer structure as the smaller binary?

(c) If the answers to (a) and (b) are both 'no' then how do I understand where these extra headers and footers are in the file.

I am using `ifort` (version 14.0.2) and I am writing the binary files on a small Linux cluster.

UPDATE: When running the same code with `OSx` and compiled with `gfortran` 7.3.0 the binary files come out with the expected sizes, as in they are always `4 x m^3 bytes`, even when `m=1024`. So this problem seems to be related to the older compiler.

UPDATE: In fact, the problem is only present when using `ifort` 14.0.2 I have updated the text to reflect this.

Comment: Does it work as expected for smaller values of m?

Comment: @ptb I think the file size for smaller values of ```m``` is always ```m^3+8```, and then it switches to ```m^3+24``` somewhere between ```m=512``` and ```m=1024```.

Comment: @VladimirF I don't know where the extra bytes are exactly. I have not tried to write a similar file from C.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you add a `status='replace'` to the `open` command and remove the `form`

Comment: @VladimirF Maybe this is more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608421/inconsistent-record-marker-while-reading-fortran-unformatted-file I can't help but think that it has something to do with the ~2Gb limit for Fortran binary files.

Comment: first thing i would do is write a really small file and look at it with a hex editor..

Comment: the large file issue is moot as with stream access there are no record markers.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce this.  I get precisely the number of bytes expected for m=512 using gfortran 7.3.1.

Comment: @ptb I get the same with 7.3.0. See my update. I guess this problem is related to the older version of gfortran (and ifort) that I was using.

Comment: Some older versions of ifort had bugs in stream, unformatted writes of large data sizes. Try a newer version.

Comment: If this is a confirmed bug someone should post that as an answer

Comment: have you looked at you output file?  The additional bytes may just be file size given on line 1.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is solved by adding `status='replace'` in the Fortran `open` command. It is *not* to do with the compiler.

With `access='stream'` and without `status='replace'`, the old binary file is not automatically replaced by the new binary file and is simply overwritten up to a certain point (https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/676047). This results in the old binary simply having bytes replaced up to the size of the new binary, while leaving any additional bytes, and the file size, unchanged. This is a problem if the new file size is smaller than the old file size. The problem difficult to diagnose because the time-stamp on the file *is* updated, so the file looks like it is new when queried using `ls -l`.

A minimal working example that recreates this problem is as follows:

```
PROGRAM write_binary_test_minimal

    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL :: a

    a=1.

    OPEN(7,file='test',form='unformatted')
    WRITE(7) a
    CLOSE(7)

    OPEN(7,file='test',form='unformatted',access='stream')
    WRITE(7) a
    CLOSE(7)

END PROGRAM write_binary_test_minimal
```

The first `write` generates a file 'test' of size `8 + 4 = 12` bytes. Where the `8` is the standard Fortran-binary header and footer and the `4` is the size in bytes of `a`. In the second `write` statement, even though `access='stream'` has been set, only the first `4` bytes of the previously-generated 'test' are overwritten, leaving the file as size `12` bytes! The solution to this is to change the second write statement to

```
OPEN(7,file='test',form='unformatted',access='stream',status='replace')
```

with an explicit `status='replace'` to ensure the old file is replaced.

Comment: If I run the code as I've written it above, compiled with `gfortran 8.1.0` I generate a file of size 12 bytes that is not replaced by the second write statement. I think this is not just an old version of `ifort` thing.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did not realize you are effectively opening the file for reading and writing and that for a sequential file it does not happen, but in a stream file you can read and write at any position with `pos=` so you cannot have the rest deleted automatically.