# how to plot with MPI in a single formatted (readable) file with MPI-IO

Tags: fortran, format, mpi, mpi-io

I am using MPI in  fortran-90 framework.

I would like to write in a single file all the data computed from different processors. I would like also to write the data in a readable format and not in the binary one.
In this moment, in my program, each processors write a single different file. As a consequence, I have another post-processing program that reads the files in order to create a single one.

Here, the specific questions:

1) it possible write a formatted file with MPI-IO options?

2) where I can study that?

Thanks in advance and,

Best Regards

Comment: Worth looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951807/using-mpi-io-to-write-fortran-formatted-files

Comment: Not directly. But if you are willing to convert the data "manually" to characters and add the end of record markers you can get something that is human readable at the end, despite being written by MPI-IO. DL_POLY does this. But I think it is probably easier to write a single binary file with MPI-IO and the post process that into the form you need