# Can't read a file with Mpi_File_Read

Tags: fortran, mpi

I hope someone can help me.  I am coding in Fortran 90 with MPI libraries.  I am trying to read files in parallel (with function Mpi_File_Read) but am unable to. Here is a simple code which demonstrates the problem:

```
    program Read_And_Write
    implicit none
    include "mpif.h"
    integer, parameter :: N = 16
    integer            :: i, this_proc, file_handle, error
    integer            :: read_data(N)
    integer            :: status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
    character(len=13)  :: file_name = 'one_array.dat'

    ! Start MPI run
    call Mpi_Init(error)
    call Mpi_Comm_Rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,  &  ! integer comm
                       this_proc,       &  ! integer rank
                       error)              ! integer error

    ! Create a file from one processor, hence "sequentially"
    if(this_proc .eq. 0) then
      open(9, file=file_name, form='unformatted')
      do i = 1, N
        write(9) i*N
      end do
      close(9)
    end if

    ! Open the same file in MPI mode
    call Mpi_File_Open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,   &  ! integer comm
                       file_name,        &  ! character filename(*)
                       MPI_MODE_RDONLY,  &  ! integer amode
                       MPI_INFO_NULL,    &  ! integer info
                       file_handle,      &  ! integer file handle
                       error)               ! integer error

    ! Read the file in MPI mode
    call Mpi_File_Read_All(file_handle,  &  ! integer file handle
                           read_data,    &  ! buffer 
                           N,            &  ! integer count
                           MPI_INTEGER,  &  ! integer datatype 
                           status,       &  ! integer status
                           error)           ! integer error

    ! Write out what you got
    do i = 1, N
      print *, 'read: ', read_data(i)
    end do

    ! End MPI run
    call Mpi_Finalize(error) 

    end program
```

Any hints or ideas what am I doing wrong here?

I am using gfortran 5.4.0 with MPICH 3.2 on Xubuntu 16.04.09

Thanks

Comment: I suggest using `use mpi` instead of `include "mpif.h"`. The compiler can then provide more useful checks about the correctness of your calls.

Comment: What is your question? What is wrong? Are you results wrong? How wrong? How do the correct results look like? Please explain where do you see a problem. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran unformatted sequential files are not compatible with MPI I/O. MPI I/O files are compatible with stream access files which work similarly as C language I/O.

Just change

```
  open(9, file=file_name, form='unformatted')
```

to

```
  open(9, file=file_name, access="stream", form='unformatted')
```

And the result will be:

```
 read:           16
 read:           32
 read:           48
 read:           64
 read:           80
 read:           96
 read:          112
 read:          128
 read:          144
 read:          160
 read:          176
 read:          192
 read:          208
 read:          224
 read:          240
 read:          256
```

Sequential Fortran files use additional record markers which MPI I/O read does not expect (e.g., [Fortran unformatted file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751185/fortran-unformatted-file-format)). You would have to make a compiler specific MPI datatype to avoid the record markers. Not worth doing it if you don't have to.

Comment: `MPI_Barrier()` might also be required before `MPI_File_open()` in order to avoid some race conditions.

Comment: Definitly. I was testing single process only and concentrating on the writing.