# Start calcurse upon log in with i3

Tags: i3

I am trying to set my i3 configuration file in order to autostart calcurse when I log in.
I have added the line

```
exec --no-startup-id calcurse
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried forking the process from within a shell script?

Comment: You were very quick in deleting your storm tracks question. There is no other way to contact you so I am writing it here. Please mark the comment as "no longer needed" after you read it. It is quite possible that the file was generated by a different compiler,perhaps Intel. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751185/unexpected-padding-in-a-fortran-unformatted-file Try the Intel compiler (now available for free) or set gfortran to use the Intel padding, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want calcurse in an open window on startup, try `exec --no-startup-id [xterm/urxvt/whatever_terminal_you_use] -e calcurse`. (most terminal use `-e` to execute a command, check the terminal help if it does not work)

If you want calcurse to run in the background (to get event notifications, and you will still be able to access the interface by executing calcurse in a terminal), go with `exec --no-startup-id calcurse --daemon`